# django - Optimize request with indirect relation without any foreign keys

Tags: django, postgresql, join, optimization, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models and a view which must join them on matching `common_field` and then perform some aggregation. The problem is for a given N=5000 rows a request is processed ~30 seconds. Here are

myapp/models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class MainModel(models.Model):
    common_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.IntegerField()
    # some other fields not relevant for the example


class AuxiliaryModel(models.Model):
    common_field = models.CharField(max_length=21)
    the_date = models.DateField()
```

myapp/serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class MainCategoryAgingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    category = serializers.IntegerField()
    age_0_99 = serializers.IntegerField()
    age_100_199 = serializers.IntegerField()
    age_200_299 = serializers.IntegerField()
    age_300_399 = serializers.IntegerField()
    age_400_plus = serializers.IntegerField()
```

myapp/views.py:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Case, Count, F, OuterRef, Subquery, Value, When
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay
from rest_framework import generics

from django_custom_join.myapp.models import AuxiliaryModel, MainModel
from django_custom_join.myapp.serializers import MainCategoryAgingSerializer


class MainCategoryAgingListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MainCategoryAgingSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            MainModel.objects
            .annotate(
                the_date=Subquery(
                    AuxiliaryModel.objects.filter(
                        common_field=OuterRef("common_field"),
                    )
                    .values("the_date"),
                ),
                curr_age=ExtractDay(Value(datetime.date.today()) - F("the_date")),
            )
            .values("category")
            .order_by("category")
            .annotate(
                age_0_99=Count(
                    Case(
                        When(curr_age__range=[0, 99], then=1),
                        output_field=models.IntegerField(),
                    ),
                ),
                age_100_199=Count(
                    Case(
                        When(curr_age__range=[100, 199], then=1),
                        output_field=models.IntegerField(),
                    ),
                ),
                age_200_299=Count(
                    Case(
                        When(curr_age__range=[200, 299], then=1),
                        output_field=models.IntegerField(),
                    ),
                ),
                age_300_399=Count(
                    Case(
                        When(curr_age__range=[300, 399], then=1),
                        output_field=models.IntegerField(),
                    ),
                ),
                age_400_plus=Count(
                    Case(
                        When(curr_age__gte=400, then=1),
                        output_field=models.IntegerField(),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        )
```

myapp/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from django_custom_join.myapp.views import MainCategoryAgingListAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    path("main-category-aging", MainCategoryAgingListAPIView.as_view())
]
```

urls.py of the project:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("myapp/", include("django_custom_join.myapp.urls")),
]
```

and a migration to fill a db with random rows:

```
import datetime
import random
import string

from django.db import migrations


def random_date(start, end):
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60
    random_second = random.randint(0, int_delta)
    return start + datetime.timedelta(seconds=random_second)


def fill_db(apps, schema_editor):
    MainModel = apps.get_model("myapp", "MainModel")
    AuxiliaryModel = apps.get_model("myapp", "AuxiliaryModel")
    start_date = datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
    end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    mains, auxiliaries = [], []
    total_count = 5_000
    count_per_category = total_count // 10
    for i in range(total_count):
        common_field = ''.join(
            random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=20),
        )
        mains.append(
            MainModel(
                common_field=common_field,
                category=i // count_per_category,
            ),
        )
        auxiliaries.append(
            AuxiliaryModel(
                common_field=common_field,
                the_date=random_date(start_date, end_date),
            ),
        )
    MainModel.objects.bulk_create(mains)
    AuxiliaryModel.objects.bulk_create(auxiliaries)


def clear_db(apps, schema_editor):
    MainModel = apps.get_model("myapp", "MainModel")
    MainModel.objects.all().delete()
    AuxiliaryModel = apps.get_model("myapp", "AuxiliaryModel")
    AuxiliaryModel.objects.all().delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("myapp", "0001_initial"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            code=fill_db,
            reverse_code=clear_db,
        )
    ]
```

Current implementation generates such query:

```
SELECT
    "myapp_mainmodel"."category",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - (
                SELECT U0."the_date" FROM "myapp_auxiliarymodel" U0 WHERE U0."common_field" = ("myapp_mainmodel"."common_field")
            )))) BETWEEN 0 AND 99
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_0_99",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - (
                SELECT U0."the_date" FROM "myapp_auxiliarymodel" U0 WHERE U0."common_field" = ("myapp_mainmodel"."common_field")
            )))) BETWEEN 100 AND 199
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_100_199",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - (
                SELECT U0."the_date" FROM "myapp_auxiliarymodel" U0 WHERE U0."common_field" = ("myapp_mainmodel"."common_field")
            )))) BETWEEN 200 AND 299
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_200_299",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - (
                SELECT U0."the_date" FROM "myapp_auxiliarymodel" U0 WHERE U0."common_field" = ("myapp_mainmodel"."common_field")
            )))) BETWEEN 300 AND 399
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_300_399",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - (
                SELECT U0."the_date" FROM "myapp_auxiliarymodel" U0 WHERE U0."common_field" = ("myapp_mainmodel"."common_field")
            )))) >= 400
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_400_plus"
FROM "myapp_mainmodel"
GROUP BY "myapp_mainmodel"."category"
ORDER BY "myapp_mainmodel"."category" ASC;
```

Here is my manually edited query with inner join which is **~300 times faster**:

```
SELECT
    t1."category",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - t2.the_date))) BETWEEN 0 AND 99
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_0_99",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - t2.the_date))) BETWEEN 100 AND 199
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_100_199",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - t2.the_date))) BETWEEN 200 AND 299
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_200_299",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - t2.the_date))) BETWEEN 300 AND 399
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_300_399",
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN EXTRACT('day' FROM (interval '1 day' * (current_date - t2.the_date))) >= 400
            THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS "age_400_plus"
FROM "myapp_mainmodel" t1
INNER JOIN "myapp_auxiliarymodel" t2
    ON t1.common_field = t2.common_field
GROUP BY t1."category"
ORDER BY t1."category" ASC;
```

I wonder if it can be optimized in any neat django way without using raw sql.